# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#49785948) expected, got Hashie::Mash(#52717320)

Tags: activerecord, nested-attributes, ruby-grape

I'm having a Grape api and I want to save nested datas.

I have a model like this :

```
class Vehicule < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_principal, :if =>:new_record?
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

The grape api :

```
# app/controller/api/v1/vehicules.rb
resource :vehicules do
  desc "Update a vehicule."
    params do
      optional :confort, type: Float, desc: ""
      optional :user, type: Hash do
        optional :name, type: String
      end
  end
  put ':id' do
    #authenticate! @todo
    Vehicule.find(params[:id]).update(vehicule_params)
  end
```

And here is my test file

```
test "PUT /api/v1/vehicules/1" do
  put("/api/v1/vehicules/1", { 'confort' => 3.4, 'user' => {'name' => 'name changed'} }, :format => "json")
  assert(200, last_response.status)
  vehicule = Vehicule.find(1)
  assert_equal('name changed', vehicule.user.name, "Le nom de l'utilisateur aurait dû changer")
end
```

The message is

```
  1) Error: API::V1::VehiculesTest#test_PUT_/api/v1/vehicules/1: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#49785948) expected, got Hashie::Mas h(#52717320)
    app/controllers/api/v1/vehicules.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Vehicu les>'
    test/controllers/api/v1/vehicules_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:VehiculesTe st>'
```

What do I do wrong ? is it the way I'm sending the data or is it my structure/declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'user_attributes' keyword in order to use nested attributes. So you have to change your params block like this:

```rb
  params do
    optional :confort, type: Float, desc: ""
    optional :user_attributes, type: Hash do
      optional :name, type: String
    end
  end
```

The test file have to change accordingly.